# Less characteres in media queries

Tags: css

Does

```
media="(device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
```

have the same behaviour as

```
media="(device-width:320px)and(-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:2)"
```

in all cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the spaces are irrelevant in this case. You can clearly see this with any one of the CSS compressors available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. CSS is very loose with spaces.